# Get Semantic Model on SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am given a `SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext context` but what I need is a `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext` with its `SemanticModel` property in order to then ascend to the parent node which is a class declaration and then check what attributes have been placed on the type.

```
SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext givenTreeContext
/// how to get to:
SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context;

var n = context.Node;
ISymbol symbol = null;
bool hasAttributes = false;

while (n != null)
{
  if (n.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration))
  {
    symbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(n);        
    hasAttributes = symbol.GetAttributes().Any();
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    n = n.Parent;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get from `SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext` to `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext`?

(Edit) To give you an example: I want to enhance some rules (which all use the `ReportDiagnostics` method of `SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext`; like [SA1027 Use tabs correctly](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/SpacingRules/SA1027UseTabsCorrectly.cs) from StyleCop Analyzers) in a way that I can place an attribute on the enclosing type and detect its presence and then omit reporting the diagnostic like

```
if (!hasAttributes) // simplified
{ 
  context.ReportDiagnostic(...);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're registering the wrong kind of action.

Comment: I don't understand what is it that you're actually trying to do and why is `SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext` the only thing that you have. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @svick: See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Register a `SemanticModelAnalysis` instead in your `Initialize` method. Syntax ones are for syntax only without having semantic impacts.